# Is there any way to rearrange mysql rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I create a table which stores users in it like this

```
id   name   family
1    mark   zooker
2    mak    donald
```

and I optimized my code after one month and to make it optimized I deleted some rows in MySql and now its look like this for example

```
id   name   family
1    mark   zooker
3    allin  wood
```

I need to know is there any way to rearrange primary key which is id?Primary key is auto increment field

Comment: Why? The fact that there's a gap in the sequence shouldn't matter. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: each user has his id and now user with id 2 not exist ?

Comment: So what? No one's harmed by a user ID that isn't used.

Comment: its just a question why -2 ? i think this site is for asking question to help someones out there like me which has same question

Comment: The `id` should never need be visible to anything other than code.  Do you worry about memory allocations and pointers?  Let the autoincrement id do what it does.

Comment: @HiDd3N - This site has guidelines as to *how* you ask questions. Even if we ignore the "Why? You shouldn't care" aspect, this one falls under: Off-topic: Questions must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Tell us what you've tried to do, why it didn't work, and how it should work. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primary keys shouldn't change. They are the unique identifier for that record. What you're trying to do is akin to changing everyone's address on a street because one family moved out.

Properly architected, there's no harm done by having a skipped ID for a piece of data.

Comment: thanks i didnt knew this

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the same physical order but rearrange the id (although it doesn't make any sense for me, but I guess you are just practicing), you'll have to do it in 2 steps:

- Add another column (let's call it new_id) which is auto_increment also
- Update id column to match the new_id column.

RDBMs don't care about the physical order of rows.

Comment: MySQL won't allow two `auto_increment` columns, and you've missed the important step of updating any *other* tables that reference the primary key.

Comment: for practice i ask.can we drop auto increment field and add another auto increment field ? @ceejayoz ?

Comment: Yes you can, but if you drop the primary key field, there is no guarantee that the records will be retreived in the same order. This is why I suggest creating another column.